# connect mobiles and perform action on click of a button

Tags: java, android

I developed an small App in which on a click of a button , Emojis Starts Falling on you Screen.I want to install the app in two mobile of user 1 and user 2 .

I want  that When user1 Presses the button on his mobile then Emojis start falling in user2 Mobile using the above app if and only if the above app is opened on user2 mobile...How Can  I Connect user 1 Mobile to user 2 Mobile.

How can I Achieve this design.

Comment: You can archive this by pairing two devices if you want to implement this locally.
1. bluetooth connection
2. wifi hotspot connection
or if you are going to implement widely like online gaming then you can use socket programming concepts.
* I will prefer node js for this implementation.

Comment: You could use Firebase. Everything is perfectly explained in  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/. So that what you required will only be internet connection and 2 users can be in any place.. No need to be close range

Comment: wifi? Bluetooth? NFC? IRDA? cellular network?

Comment: @VladMatvienko cellular network

Comment: that is the answer - `with a cellular network`. One device is a server, second is a client.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you Idea on how you should achieve this.
You might have Idea on Google cloud messaging/Fire base cloud messaging.
You must register both the users to FCM, and you should send a message (through FCM)from user 1 to the registered TOken generated by user 2. 
When you receive a message through FCM in user 2, This is a call to do yourEmoji falling animation. If you want to know more about FCM

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Or one more concept would be multiplayer concept in Google game play services.
You can know more about it https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer